# Update HTML content with data from external PHP post request

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

I have two pages. mobile.html and video.php. mobile.html sends an `ajax` post request with a single variable. video.php should read that variable and pass it to a JS function in the same page that would change a video control.  I tried to use this logic:

1. mobile.html sends an ajax post request
2. video.php has PHP code inside a div to read the request and get the variable
3. reload video.php and allow the JS code in the same page to get the variable from inside the div
4. pass the variable to the intended JS function in video.php.
5. execute the function on the video.

here is my code and for simplicity I replaced the video with `<p>` tag. mobile.html code works fine. my problem is in video.php

**mobile.html**

```
 $.post("video.php", {gesture: action}, function(response){
           $("#result").html('response: '+response);
         });
```

**video.php**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
//a div to hold the value of post variable
  <div id="dom-target" style="display: none">
    <?php
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
    {
      
      
    if( isset($_POST["gesture"]))
      {//put the variable value inside the div to fitch it later
        $gesture = $_POST["gesture"];
        echo $gesture;
      }
      else {
        echo "none";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo json_encode("PHP no post");
    }

    ?>
  </div>
//p content should be updated with the value of $gesture
  <p id="update">
    should be updated with post variable using JS 
  </p>
  <script>
//get post variable from the div
  var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
  var myData = div.textContent;
  $("#update").html(myData);

console.log("myData: "+myData);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been up over my head for a week trying to work around this problem but I cannot seem to get the result that I want because when I reload the page I find my variable in the ajax callback function :/

the output I am getting currently is "PHP no post" in video.php and myData: "PHP no post" in the console of video.php which is ok because obviously the first time I run the page it is not through a post request. however when I click the button that triggers the post request in mobile.html I get the output of this line `console.log("myData: "+myData);` with the correct data but in mobile.html console! not in video.php console. meaning that the code is run in the callback function of the ajax post request in mobile.html.

I failed to find a way to update the `<p id="update">` in the currently opened video.php page. Now I am not even sure I can do it with PHP since it runs only on a server and JS runs only on the web browser.

***My question is:*** can I do the steps explained above using PHP ?
**IF YES** can you help me figure out a way to dynamically and instantly update the video.php page using a post call sent from mobile.html ? or any other way that would work with PHP?

**IF NOT** can you suggest what other languages/platforms I can use to do what I want to do ?

**UPDATE:**
to have an idea of what I want to achieve, I did two pages using `localstorage`. open [mobil.html](http://engibtvcontrol.com/youtubeplayer/mobile.html) in one window and then open[video.html](http://engibtvcontrol.com/youtubeplayer/video.html)
in another window side by side. play the video then use the controls on `mobile.html` and see how it changes the playback in `video.html`.
I want to be able to do the same thing but *remotely using `PHP`* because I have to use a real mobile instead of `mobile.html`

Comment: You can use store `$gesture` in `$_SESSION` whenever ajax is call and when you come to video.php page check if session value is not empty show that value or don't use ajax here directly redirect to required page .

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you are trying to build here. I'm pretty sure that PHP and JS have the means to build what you want, but I think that your approach should be different. I'll try to help you out once you've explained what the result should be.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier what I am trying to do is to dynamically update `<p>` in video.php whenever it receives an `ajax post call` from mobile.html. what I am getting instead is that the result of my  `JS` code above in video.php is executed in mobile.html in the `ajax callback function` instead of updating `<p>` in video.php

Comment: @Swati I tried to use `$_SESSION` only in video.php. do you mean I should use `$_SESSION` in mobile.html too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question for those who have been rumbling about not understanding how to update a part of a web page in real time without having to reload it. **Long story short**,  To achieve the scenario I mentioned in my question I have to use `WebSockets` as @EmielZuurbier pointed out in the comments of the first answer, so thanks to him.

There are tons of ways to do that.**For beginners**, you have to be patient and make sure you understand how it works properly before you jump in coding. Also, know that some codes that are available on the internet *work only on the backend* and that there are specific ways to make websockets work on a browser. **In my case I used** Node.js in the server side and isomorphic-ws in the client side in a web browser

here are some helpful references that helped me during the past week:

- Here is the official site for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) for installation and documentation.
- This is a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5OVcTdt_OU) to get you started if you are new to WebSockets. it explains Websockets and display real implementation of it.
- Here you can find documentatino of [WebSocket()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebSockets).
- This video demonstrate how to implement a websocket in your local
  machine (aka laptop): [How to Create a WebSocket Server & Client](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IKUKDf7mA0).
- **Be aware** that the video above will *work only on backend* which you can run using Terminal on mac or Command line in Windows. **To work it on a
  browser** I used [isomorphic-ws](https://github.com/heineiuo/isomorphic-ws)  which is a wrapper that allows
  websockets to work on web browsers.

I wish this could help anyone who was stuck like me on how to implement a real time communication between two ends.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your `gesture` value to the `video.php` file, but you are not using it to get a new paragraph element with the updated value in it. PHP should do its work on the server and JavaScript strictly on the frontend.

Keep your POST request the same.

```
$.post("video.php", {gesture: action}, function(response) {
  $("#result").html('response: ' + response);
});
```

But modify the response that server returns. The `gesture` value is in the `$_POST` array. From there you can use it to render a new paragraph and echo or return this to the frontend.

```
<?php

// Set default value.
$gesture = 'none';
if ( isset( $_POST[ "gesture" ] ) ) { 
  // Overwrite if there is a gesture value.
  $gesture = $_POST[ "gesture" ];
}

// Echo a new paragraph with the gesture in it.
echo '<p id="update">' . $gesture . '</p>';
exit;
?>
```

Comment: this is right I get the value of `$gesture` where I want but the result does not appear in the currently opened video.php page. it appears in the response of the callback function of the ajax post call in mobile.html. so what I want to do is update video.php that is open in the browser each time I hit the post call from mobile.html. I hope it is clear

Comment: Ahh, well now it is. You want to communicate to open tabs of the video page and control some things there from the mobile page, right? You are looking for either [Web Sockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) or maybe the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API). You can't really "talk" to other pages with HTTP. Web Sockets would be the most suitable one for your case.

Comment: You're trying to build a remote control for your video?

Comment: yes exactly! I am trying to build a remote control. refer to the update in my question to see the example I added. I think Web Sockets API makes a lot of sense. I will try them and get back. thank you

Answer (score 0):

first just please organize the code a little bit so you can see the code well

1. you need to put the post request inside a function with a trigger action because with that it would be never called
2. you need to make sure that you are getting the correct data in 'action' variable (console.log it before the post)

(if $.post is not working for some reason download jquery and use it locally because it might not be in the slim CDN)

Hint:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log(gesture); //check this in the console after refreshing the page
    $.post("video.php", {gesture: action}, function(response){
       $("#result").html('response: '+response);
    });
});
```

Comment: kindly refer to the example in the UPDATED section of my question to have a better understanding of my problem. currently,  mobile.html works exactly as it is supposed to. my problem is in updating the content of video.php after it reads the post variable. I will pursue Emiel Zuurbier's suggestion to use one of the APIs he suggested and update you all. thanks